# Using streams to read a text file and save to the BigInteger array

Tags: java, file, java-stream, biginteger

What would be the right way to read a text file, split numbers by `,` and save all of them to a `BigInteger` array?

```
BigInteger[] a = new BigInteger[1000];
try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath))) {

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Can it be done directly or should you first save the whole file as a big `String` and then split it with streams?

```
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath)));
```

Comment: what does the input file look like ? does it have any seperators ? or does each line represent one value ?

Comment: @springe Like I said in the original post, I'd like to split them by `, ` delimiter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can split the each string in stream by using `,` as delimiter, and then convert them into `BigInteger` array

```
BigInteger[] array = stream.map(str -> str.split(","))
                           .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                           .map(BigInteger::new)
                           .toArray(BigInteger[]::new);
```

Or as approach suggested by @Lino says Reinstate Monica you can also use `Pattern` object to split the strings

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(",");

BigInteger[] array = stream.flatMap(pattern::splitAsStream)
                           .map(BigInteger::new)
                           .toArray(BigInteger[]::new);
```

Comment: instead of using `stream.map(str -> str.split(",")).flatMap(Arrays::stream)` you can use a precompiled `java.util.regex.Pattern` and then write `stream.flatMap(yourPattern::splitAsStream)`